# Java to Scala conversion

Tags: scala

I'm trying to convert the following Java code into Scala:

```
ImageRecognitionPlugin imageRecognition = (ImageRecognitionPlugin)nnet.getPlugin(ImageRecognitionPlugin.class)
```

It runs in Java (full code: http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/image_recognition.html).

What would it be in Scala? I'm confused about the "`(ImageRecognitionPlugin).nnet`" bit and I get the following error when I drop the "`(ImageRecognitionPlugin)`".

**"error: object ImageRecognitionPlugin is not a value"**

Comment: What is the Scala code you are using?

Comment: http://www.javatoscala.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In scala you need to specify whether you are create a mutable (var) or immutable (val) variable.  You also need to use classOf and instanceOf instead of .class and the (cast):

```
val imageRecognition = nnet.getPlugin(classOf[ImageRecognitionPlugin]).asInstanceOf[ImageRecognitionPlugin]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
val imageRecognition:ImageRecognitionPlugin = 
    nnet.getPlugin(classOf[ImageRecognitionPlugin])
```

Let's break this down:

```
val
```

This declares an *immutable* value.  That means that this value will always point to this specific instance.  If you used a var instead this would be a variable instead.

```
imageRecognition:ImageRecognitionPlugin
```

This tells us 1) the name of the value and 2) its type.  Instead of Foo aFoo, as in Java, Scala uses aFoo:Foo.

```
nnet.getPlugin(classOf[ImageRecognitionPlugin])
```

classOf[Foo] is Scala's equivalent of Foo.class in Java.

Comment: If the cast is really required in Java (e.g. if `getPlugin` returns an `Object`), this code won't work. Then you need an `asInstanceOf` as shown by Chris Shain.

Comment: Thanks Ryan - asInstanceOf was also required